# Simple sdl game very slow while cpu at 1.2%

Tags: c, performance, rendering, sdl, frame

I wrote a simple 2d tile based game and ran it on 2 computers. On comp1 it's very slow, on comp2 it's lightening fast.

Comp1's cpu is a little slower, but it can play other sdl games (even inside emulaters) and simple 3d games, fast enough.

So I ran the game on both computers using only cpu rendering: both ran at the same speed.
Then I switched to gpu rendering and the 2nd computer went really fast (200+fps) but the first stayed at the same pace, around 20fps.

So I assumed either the hw acceleration is not working on comp1 or the cpu is clogged with my calculations.

I logged all the error handling and can confirm both computers support the hw acceleration and the texture sizes (i know this for a fact because the cpu bound version of the game has no flip and so the character always faces the same way ;)

So then it has to be a slow cpu on the first computer, right? But when I check the cpu stats the game only takes 1,2% cpu, and overall load is around 2% cpu

So the cpu is sitting mostly idle while my game crawls along :(

The game is a few 1000 lines of code now, so here are some of the statements that I think pertain to this problem:

Main game loop:

```
while (!quit)
{

    GameEngine_Tick(gameType->fps, false, 0);

    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0))
    {
        int windowID = event.window.windowID;

        if (event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE &&
            event.window.windowID == screens[0].windowID) quit = true;

        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:

            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT)  { Key_Left(); }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT) { Key_Right();}
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP)    { Key_Up(); }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN)  { Key_Down(); }
            break;  // end key_down.
        } // switch event type
    }

    GameEngine_Render();

   }
```

Frame rate limiting in GameEngine_Tick:

```
void GameEngine_Tick(int fps, bool bIsRegTestStep, Uint8 TDir)
{
unsigned int frametime = 1000 / fps;
unsigned int currentTime;

const Uint8* keystates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL); // do not free.

SDL_PumpEvents(); // upd keystates to get keyboard inputs.

    // Get KB input - todo: later GetInputFromSelectedInputDevice (checks kb/xbox etc)
    if (keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT])  GameLeft();
    else if (keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) GameRight();

Sprites_Tick();

// set framerate by waiting if needed.
currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
if (currentTime - prevTime < (frametime))
{
    //Sleep the remaining frame time 
    if (fps > 0) SDL_Delay((frametime)-(currentTime - prevTime)); /* fps-1 == MAX == no delay*/
}
prevTime = currentTime;

}
```

create renderer:

```
ren = nullptr;
if (bForceCPURender == false) ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);// | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
if (nullptr == ren)
{
    if (bForceCPURender == false)
    {
        Log("Info: SDL_CreateRenderer with SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED failed. Trying default.");
    }
    bForceCPURender = true;

    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (nullptr == ren)
    {
        Log("Info: SDL_CreateRenderer with default also failed.");
        SDLDestroy();
        return -1;
    }
    else Logs("Info: success using default renderer.");
}
else Logs("Info: success, using SDL_CreateRenderer with SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED.");
```

Creating textures or surfaces:

```
spriteMapTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(ren, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET,
    x_pixPerCharInStageMap * roomWidthInChars  * gameRoomMatrix_w,
    y_pixPerCharInStageMap * roomHeightInChars * gameRoomMatrix_h);

// If GPU cannot handle size of stage map: try to do CPU preRendering. (gpu is texture, cpu is surface).
if (NULL == spriteMapTexture || bForceCPUStageRenderAnyway == true)
{
        spriteMapSurface = GameEngine_CreateRGBSurface(x_pixPerCharInStageMap * roomWidthInChars  * gameRoomMatrix_w, y_pixPerCharInStageMap * roomHeightInChars * gameRoomMatrix_h);
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `frametime`? Also, when using a hardware renderer you can be very confident that `SDL_RenderPresent()` is able to block until vertical sync — that is far and away the cleanest SDL way of yielding CPU time.

Comment: frametime is 1000/40. Which limits the framerate to 40fps on other computers. On comp1 no matter what framerate I set or even if I skip framelimiting, i'm stuck at 20fps. I tried both with vsync on and off. I'm not sure i need to yield more cpu time as the cpu is basically idling at 1,2% anyway?

Comment: Can sdl_pollevent be slower on some computers than others?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (!quit)
{
    GameEngine_Tick(gameType->fps, false, 0);

    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0))
    ^^ wat
    {
        // process event
    }

    GameEngine_Render();
}
```

Right now you're only processing a single event each frame.  Used to be SDL could only buffer 128 events before dropping them, nowadays I think they're up to 64k.  So if, for example, you have a high-report-rate gaming mouse (500-1000 Hz sampling) your event queue will get backed up far faster than a regular mouse (125 Hz).  Same for any other event type SDL can generate; some systems will have different event generation rates than others.

You want to process *every* event in the queue before rendering a frame:

```
while (!quit)
{
    GameEngine_Tick(gameType->fps, false, 0);

    // NOTE: if -> while
    while( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
    {
        // process event
    }

    GameEngine_Render();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a key piece of insight I was missing! Would it also explain why comp1 is so much slower than comp2 while still only using 1.2 % cpu?

Comment: I've added the gametick logic, as I'm only using the SDL_PollEvent() in the main loop to check if the game needs to quit or the window is manipulated. In Gametick I check keyboard values and move the game along according to that input. Could it be I'm making a similar oversight in the use of SDL_PumpEvents() and SDL_GetKeyboardState() ?

Comment: Made the updates but no speed increase :( Any other ideas?

Comment: So it seems even if the gfx card supports the hw acc. and requested texture sizes, it may still render equally slow as the cpu bound sw renderer. Guess I should have considered that a possibility from the start. My solution was to complete all cpu bound processing in the tics, but then only call the actual render routines once every 3 tics. That got rid of my lag (at the expense of some sightly less smooth movements on the sprites.